# What are the dangers of eating spoiled meat?

Tags: diet, infection, food-safety

Most people seem to naturally understand that spoiled food is "gross." But what are the actual dangers of eating it? Does it taste bad, or does it have serious potential to make one sick?

Clearly, this is an incredibly broad question, so I'll zero in on meats, specifically muscle and organ meats from chicken, beef and pork. What bacteria/fungi/parasites tend to grow on these meats as they spoil, and how are they dangerous to humans?

**Edit**

I asked this question because there's plenty of information online about the consequences of eating *undercooked* food, but nothing I can find about eating *spoiled* food. I'm asking specifically what happens when you eat meat products that have gone bad.